# Focus on previously opened window from new modal dialog

Tags: c#, winforms, modal-dialog, windows-forms-designer

My situation is the following:

I have a main form. I open another window (1) with `Show()` method. It is not modal. I open a second modal window (2) with `ShowDialog`.

Now, I search through open forms and find window (1). I am able to bring it up, focus on it, but I cannot use any control in it - it is locked. Is it possible to "unlock" that window (1) without closing it and re-opening it?

Comment: If the modal window (2) is a child of (1), no, you can't, as it is default behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

[Default behaviour for this situation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx) is to block the current window and wait for the result of a dialog:

> When a `Window` class is instantiated, it is not visible by default. ShowDialog shows the window, **disables all other windows in the application**, and returns only when the window is closed. This type of window is known as a modal window.

The only thing you can do is to set the `Owner` property via [`Form.ShowDialog Method (IWin32Window)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w61zzfwe.aspx) override, but this will not "unlock" other windows, as you are using the modal window:

> [`Window.ShowDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx) Method
>   Opens a window and returns only when the newly opened window is closed.